# making a webpage cross browser compatible

Tags: css, internet-explorer

i want to display my webpage in all the browser versions...my code is working fine in mozilla and chrome but not working properly in internet explorer.
here is the css code which is not compatible with IE it's seems....

**EDIT**

Struggling to create a web page for cross browser and multiple resolution support for the past 2 months,As my design have multiple issues with resolution and browser support.i am new to this designing thing and i dont have any idea on how to this.i saw a article regarding multiple resolution support which states that we have to use regular css code which is supported by all the browsers under all resolutions.Also i heard that we have to put our normal `<div></div>` inside a container,so that the design will never collide which each other when it is viewed under lower resolution.below is my css code which will work under 1680X1050 and only in Mozilla.currently iam using a template which works fine under all circumstances.give me some sample examples of a perfect design so that i will learn to design my own

```
#image img
{
padding:6px;
border-top:0px solid #ddd;
border-left:0px solid #ddd;
border-bottom:0px solid #c0c0c0;
border-right:0px solid #c0c0c0;
display:inline;
position:relative;
top:-210px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto; 
}
#hori
{
width: 70em;
margin-left:350px;
position:absolute;
}

#hori ul li
{
display:inline;
float:left;
list-style:none;
}

#hori ul
{
padding:0;
margin-top:-620px; 
}

#hori li
{
display: inline;   
padding:0;
text-align:center;
width:7em; 
float:left;
list-style:none;
height:25px;
margin-left:15px;
background:#38ACEC;
-moz-border-radius: 70px;
border-radius: 70px;
}

#verti 
{
float:bottom;
width:200px;
margin-top:50px;
position:relative;
display: inline;
}

#verti ul li
{
list-style:none;
text-decoration:none; 
}

#verti ul
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#verti li
{
width:150px;
background:#38ACEC;
margin-bottom:9px;
position:relative;
top:170px;
-moz-border-radius:80px;
border-radius:80px;
text-align:center;
}

#slideshow 
{
position:relative;
height:500px;
right:-570px;
top:-280px
}

#slideshow img
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:8;
}

#slideshow img.active
{
z-index:10;
}

#slideshow img.last-active
{
z-index:9;
}
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
width:650px;
position:relative;
right:-480px;
margin-top:-35%;
}
th
{
background-color:#38ACEC;
color:white;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but no one is gonna decipher what the CSS is supposed to be doing with the HTML and a preview of what you want and what you get (that is wrong)

Comment: This is a Q&A site – would you mind to ask a question?

Comment: Internet Explorer is, by far, the worst browser on the planet, and that's an uphill battle we all face every day, and you see that in your markup working in all browsers except IE. However, as scibuff noted, without a link, a jsfiddle, or the complete markup, anything we say to help is only a wild guess.

Comment: i will give the link of jsfiddle asap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KyRus/28/ i cant see the horizontal menus and images if the page is viewed through IE

Comment: It's not working in Opera either, unless you want your headers hanging outside of their containers. http://i.imgur.com/96UEe.png

Comment: double trouble IE now opera...trying my best

Comment: you should utilise reset css. there are many (YUI, Normalize) but i would recommend meyerweb reset found at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. reset css basically clears UserAgent CSS (CSS that comes along with browsers) making common ground for all browsers (not only IE but FF, Chrome also). Read more for Reset CSS existence at http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't ask any question may I presume the question is: how should I make this css compatible in IE browsers?

There are actually several ways to do this:

- Find out wich css properties are not functioning correct in IE  check this site for some common CSS mistakes http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml
- Add an inline filter to render different css when using IE  followed with the IE compatible css if you want to make this negative just add `!` before the condition.
- make 2 different css files wich are included in the top of your html page with the same filter

`<!--[if lt IE #version]>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleIE.css" />
```

hope this helps you out.